# Dart + JSON + Neo4j: Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Tags: json, neo4j, dart

I've been playing around with Dart and Neo4j lately, with dreams of building Really Cool Things with these new technologies. I think I understand REST and can wrap my head around JSON. I've read both the Dart and the Neo4j documentation on using REST and JSON within each respective domain. Putting the two together, however, I have met with only very limited success. I'm really hoping someone out there might know of a tutorial or something that can get me started.

So far, I've been able to get Dart to query the database at *12.34.56.78:7474* and get it to return the address for the root node (*12.34.56.78:7474/db/data*) and the admin interface. When I try to query the root node, though, I get nothing back, even though, as far as I can tell in the documentation, I should be getting information about the database version and so on. At least that's what I see when I use RESTClient to view the database root node.

I'm a pretty experienced IT tech and coder, but I have to admit this is new territory for me.

Comment: Hi Darren, you might have better luck posting some code snippets and any errors you might see. As written, this question is very hard to debug for you. You could point us to your github project for this code, too. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Seth! I have a feeling that my best approach is going to be learning Dart inside and out first. I'm still pretty weak there, and jumping right into JSON and REST stuff is probably out of the question at the moment. I was just hoping I could see *something* working so I could know if Dart+Neo4j is worth pursuing. I do have a project in mind for it.

Comment: Hi Darren, if you want to learn Dart, there is probably more written about using Dart in the browser. Maybe start that way? Either way you go, have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out, I don't think there is a tutorial for Dart + Neo4j, at the time of this writing.

You might be interested in Dart + MongoDB by using http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart

Answer (score 1):

Would be really cool if you could start that Dart-Neo4j integration and then let the community know about it?

/peter

Comment: That would be cool, wouldn't it? I honestly don't know how far I'll get, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The thing is, the more I read about document store databases and MongoDB specifically, the more I think they're a better fit for what I need here at work. For my personal project, I still want a graph database, but that's not going to be a Dart application. I plan to write that in C# and use (or come up with) some kind of embedded graph store.

Comment: Ok, let us know the progress!

Comment: I am currently writing a driver for neo4j ("neo4dart" https://github.com/mmaquevice/neo4dart). It is at an early stage but you can already perform basic CRUD operations.